# Angular 14 running npm install after upgrade from 12 throwing lot of error

Tags: angular-cli, angular14

I am upgrading my angular app from v12 to v14. I did the following:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

now when i do '`ng version`' i get following i.e there is error against typescript and @angular-devkit/build-angular. Also none of the packages got installed.

[image]

Can anyone please point out what should i do to fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: `npm install -g @angular/cli` This command installs the CLI globally, but changes nothing in the repo

Comment: See https://update.angular.io/?v=12.0-14.0 for instructions how to update your project.